# Dynamically adding Relative layout into Linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a `LinearLayout` inside `DrawerLayout` named "container". At the run, time I am trying to add a `RelativeLayout` inside the "container". It causes `RelativeLayout` alignment does not work properly i.e. progress coming over logo image.

**Relative Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp">


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_network_error"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/no_network"
            android:textColor="#E10000"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_software_version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Version"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**DrawerLayout having container**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Injecting layout at Runtime**

```
protected View getRootView(View view) {
        View sliderLayout = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.slider_layout, null);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) sliderLayout.findViewById(R.id.contentPanel);
        layout.addView(view);
        return sliderLayout;
    }
```

Comment: Can you use the layout inspector to view the actual layout when the app is running? If this doesn't help: the inspector should generate a file of the retrieved layout, which you can show us to help further

Comment: Since you put the logo `ImageView` before `ProgressBar` in the `RelativeLayout`, it is desirable to see the `ProgressBar` over the logo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure where `getRootView()` resides in your code. If you clarify, I can provide better solution.

However, I created a project with navigation drawer activity, defined the RelativeLayout to be added dynamically in layout_to_be_added.xml, and did the following experiment in `onCreate()` of MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...

    final LinearLayout contentPanel = findViewById(R.id.contentPanel);
    contentPanel.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            View layoutToBeAdded = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.layout_to_be_added, null);
            contentPanel.addView(layoutToBeAdded);
            // contentPanel.invalidate();
        }
    });
}
```

This resulted in the problem you mentioned, progress bar and text is not below the centered logo, as seen here:

[image: Probably the layout params are not correct...].

It seems null root causes wrong calculations or evaluations, therefore I updated `inflate()` line as follows:

```
View layoutToBeAdded = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.layout_to_be_added, contentPanel, false);
```

Here we provide container as root but we don't attach slider layout to it. This way the root is only used to calculate correct LayoutParams and we get the expected result as seen below:

[image: Correct result]

Comment: from where did you get object "sliderLayout" at first line of method?The view "contentPanel" is inside view of sliderLayout.

Comment: I deleted it, it was blind shot since I don't know where `getRootView` is and how your whole implementation is. The solution holds for my example though.

Comment: getRootView  was called before setContentView(); as you have already done.

Comment: You cannot override `getRootView` in an Activity, so I wonder where you override it.

Comment: It is not overrided method but its created by me which will get called in setContentView () of Parent  .

Comment: Anyways appreciate your efforts and got a hint from your perspective. So accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed below the line

```
contentPanel.addView(view);
```

to

```
contentPanel.addView(view,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

It worked for me.